# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

Tags: python, datetime

I get the following error when I try to print `expensedate`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "expense.py", line 36, in <module>
    print_expense_month('nov16')
  File "expense.py", line 31, in print_expense_month
    print expensedate + " | " + description + " | " + "%.2f" % (cost)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'
```

Line 34 is the `print` line below. I just want to print the date.

```
while description is not None:
    expensedate = sheet.cell(row = i, column = COLUMN_DATE).value
    description = sheet.cell(row = i, column = COLUMN_DESCRIPTION).value
    cost = sheet.cell(row=i, column=COLUMN_COST).value

    #expensedate format = 2016-11-01 00:00:00

    if description is not None:
        print expensedate + " | " + description + " | " + "%.2f" % (cost)

    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if all you want is a print then, change your print line from

```
print expensedate + " | " + description + " | " + "%.2f" % (cost)
```

to

```
print "%s | %s | %.2f" % (expensedate, description, cost)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to add `datetime` type to `str`. In python you need to convert types.

```
print str(expensedate) + " | " + description + " | " + "%.2f" % (cost)
```

If you want different datetime format use `strftime` https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Also I would suggest using [string's `format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) instead of string concatination, which is more feature full and doesn't have problem with types

```
print "{} | {} | {:.2f}".format(expensedate, description, cost)
```